# Problem to log in at a postgreSQL database on AWS cloud

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a server on AWS platform running an app. The database is on postgreSQL. The authentication is with .pem archives.
A few days ago, I was reported that the space of database was reaching the asigned quota, so I increase the quota through the RDS module on the cloud.
After doing it, I can't log in through pgAdmin to check the database. Nothing else was modified.

When I try to log in at the database I get this message:"Failed to create the SSH tunnel. Error: Could not establish session to SSH gateway"

The loggin configuration has always been like this (before increasing the quota I was able lo log in without any problems):
Use SSH tunneling: yes
Tunnel host: the IP assigned is the same and is still available.
Tunnel port: the port number is specified
Username: the username is specified
Authentication: Identity File
Identity file: It exist at the local route on my PC.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the error message, the problem is with the ssh side of things, not with PostgreSQL itself.  I'd just use the ssh command line to debug the ssh problem directly, that should be easier than trying to debug it through pgAdmin4.